# if items overflow apply scroll dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldv10oz5/2/

How would I set div to scroll dynamically if list bigger than div?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 150px; height: 75px;">
  <div data-bind="foreach: {data:teams}">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


function Team(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
}

function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.teams = ko.observableArray([
    new Team('red'),
    new Team('blue'),
    new Team('yellow'),
    new Team('green'),
    new Team('orange'),
  ]);
}

var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to parent div (this with border) css:

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Is there a way to subscribe to an event after all the teams have been loaded? (normally, this would be an ajax load)? Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: I think It is another question. Here I can say that ajax call has a callback in which you can perform some action